# How to find the 2nd largest number in the array, but return the last index that the value appears in?

Tags: c, arrays, math

My actual problem is to find the number in a data set with the 2nd highest frequency. I'm initializing an array that is the size of the largest number in the data set and then incrementing the corresponding indexes in the array each time the number appears in the data set. If more than two indexes shares the 2nd highest frequency then I need to return the larger index. My code returns the correct answer in some cases, but not all and I am having trouble finding the error in my logic.

```
int secondFreq(int data[], int maxNum){
    int highest = 0;
    int secondHighest = 0;
    int x;

    for(x = 0; x < maxNum; x++){
        if(data[x] > data[highest]){
            secondHighest = highest;
            highest = x;
        }
        else if (data[x] > data[secondHighest]){
            secondHighest = x;
        }
        else if (data[x] == data[secondHighest]){
            secondHighest = x;
        }
    }

    return secondHighest + 1;
}
```

Here is an example of an array that yields the wrong answer. The left number is the index and the right number is the value stored at that index. My function returns 12 (11th index+1), but it should be returning 5 (4th index + 1).

```
    0 - 2
    1 - 2
    2 - 5
    3 - 2
    4 - 5
    5 - 4
    6 - 2
    7 - 2
    8 - 6
    9 - 4
    10 - 3
    11 - 6
    12 - 2
    13 - 2
    14 - 3
```

Comment: Step through the function with your debugger, that should tell you when the variables are wrong.

Comment: `if (secondHighest[x])` makes no sense.`secondHighest` isn't an array, and you're missing the body of the `if`.

Comment: @Barmar I fixed that. That part was just a bad copy/paste job.

Comment: Why do you add 1 to `secondHighest` when returning it?

Comment: You can combine the 2nd and 3rd `if` by using `>=`.

Comment: @Barmar I add 1 because indexes start at 0 and my numbers start at 1.

Comment: Can you give an example of input that produces an incorrect result?

Comment: @Barmar I have posted an example.

Comment: Is the quantity of data so large that it would be unreasonable to make a copy?

Comment: So your code is making a lot of sense. When there is a tie for first (at 6), it breaks it and puts the other in 2nd place. You are saying when there is a tie for first, you actually want the number in 3rd place?

Comment: @JeremyKahan Yes, because there is two 6's I need to return the 3rd highest value. So, even if every number in the data set was 6, but just 1 was a different number I need to accommodate for that different number.

Comment: you need `else if (data[x] == data[highest]){
         highest = x;
        }`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY is correct. Without that, when it gets to a duplicate of the highest, it makes that the second highest, because it's higher than the old second highest.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I added that before the first else if and it worked! Thank you so much. If you post a full comment I can verify it as right.

Comment: also your logic is wrong If first element is larger than other elements.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY do I need to do an if and else statement before the for loop to check the first element being bigger?

Comment: I think `secondHighest` is the first state that it should be undetermined.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'll do some experimenting. Thanks for letting me know about that logic error because I doubt the random number generator I made would give me that as a test case.

Comment: I know it is not satisfying to do something less efficient, but it feels like a 2-pass solution would be easier not to mess up on some subtle point. That is, go through once and find the max value (not index). Then go through again and find the index of the max value of everything that is not == to the max value.

Comment: @JeremyKahan I had considered that, but we are being graded directly on our efficiency with this particular assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two problems:

1. You will need to set `highest = x;` in the case of `data[x] == data[highest]`.
2. `secondHighest` should be initially pending.

The following is an example modification:

```
int secondFreq(int data[], int maxNum){
    int highest = 0;
    int secondHighest, secondFlag = 0;//secondFlag : Whether secondHighest has been determined, 0 : undetermined, 1(Not 0) : determined
    int x;

    for(x = 1; x < maxNum; x++){
        if(data[x] > data[highest]){
            secondHighest = highest;
            highest = x;
            secondFlag = 1;
        }
        else if (data[x] == data[highest]){
            highest = x;
        }
        else if (secondFlag == 0 || data[x] >= data[secondHighest]){
            secondHighest = x;
            secondFlag = 1;
        }
    }

    if(secondFlag)
        return secondHighest + 1;
    else
        return 0;//All elements same
}
```

Comment: This fails in the case that the 2nd else if never executes. This happens in the data set pointed out in an answer above:  (0 - 2) - (1 - 2) - (2 - 5)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. I'm AFK right now, so I will check when I get home.

Comment: found the error! I just missed that you set the secondFlag to 1 in the first if statement. It works perfectly now. Thank you for helping me solve this.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the second '6'(index 11) will go to the 'else if (data[x] > data[secondHighest])' and update the 'secondHighest' to be the same as 'highest'. This logic cannot deal with the condition where there are multiple highest value.
To fix, you can put a 'else if(data[x] == data[highest])' before other 'else if'.

However, you will get another incorrect anwser if your data set is as below:

```
0 - 2
1 - 2
2 - 5
```

I will change the code to be more clear and readable as below:

```
int secondFreq(int data[], int maxNum){
    int secondLargestValue = findsecondLargestValue(data);
    return findIndexofValue(data, secondLargestValue) + 1;
}

int findsecondLargestValue(int data) {
    ...
}

int findIndexofValue(int data, int value) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I made the change to add the new elseif statement. I then tried the data set that you provided and my function returned a 2 (1st index + 1), which would be the correct answer. Another change I made to my code was leaving secondHighest uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

Were it not for the efficiency consideration of being 2 pass, (so this is not going to be the best answer), I would want to say something like:

```
int secondFreq(int data[], int maxNum)
{
    double          highestVal = data[0];   // start with the first
                        // entry
    int             secondHighest = -1; // will send back 0 if everything
                    // ties for first
    int             x;      // for loop index

    for (x = 1; x < maxNum; x++) {
    if (data[x] > highestVal) {
        highestVal = data[x];
    }
    };
    for (x = 1; x < maxNum; x++) {
    if (data[x] != highestVal)
        &&((secondHighest == -1) || (data[x] >= data[secondHighest])) {
        secondHighest = x;
        }
    }


    return secondHighest + 1;
}
```

It is harder to mess up, though it does look through twice.